# Defining a new tblr environment results in a Misplaced alignment error

Tags: environments, alignment, tabularray, renewcommand

By modifying the `awesome-cv` class with the following I'm redefining the `cvskills` environment using the `tabularray` package

```
\NewEnviron{cvskills}{%
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\BODY]{
    colspec={Q X},
  }
    \BODY
  \end{tblr}
}

% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} \\
}
```

However when using it like it should be results in a `Misplaced alignment tab character &. \cvskill #1#2->\skilltypestyle {#1} &`

```
\begin{cvskills}

  \cvskill{Programming}{Skill1, Skill2, Skill3}
  
\end{cvskills}
```

The `cvskills` environment works when inserting values like in a normal table like

```
\begin{cvskills}

  Programming & Skill1, Skill2, Skill3 \\
  
\end{cvskills}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and expand `\cvskills`.

In the following example I use an unmodified `awesome-cv` and do `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` and `\renewcommand`.

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{cvskills}{+b}{%
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\cvskill]{
    colspec={Q X},
  }
    #1
  \end{tblr}
}{}

% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\renewcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} \\
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {My Resume}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

\begin{cvskills}
  \cvskill{Programming}{Skill1, Skill2, Skill3}
\end{cvskills}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `\NewEnviron` or `\newenviron*` not working in my case? Also, what the `expand` option does?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro That's a quirk of `tabularray`. Foreign commands need to be expanded (or the `&` in them wouldn't be recognized). In the documentation the author uses `\NewEnviron`, but he shouldn't. The problem is that you can expand `\BODY`, but not commands inside it. With `\NewDocumentEnvironment` there's no intermediate step with `\BODY`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you are right. I will replace `\NewEnviron` with `\NewDocumentEnvironment` in the documentation in a later version of `tabularray`. Thanks.